# File creating and wirting content in .txt file

Tags: android

I am creating a file with getFilesDir() + file name what I am getting is filesfileName.txt, can you please tell me why I am getting this file name instead of fileName.txt.. thanks for your concern.

---

```
File file = new File(mContext.getFilesDir() + fileName+ ".txt");
            if (!file.exists()) {

                file.createNewFile();
                FileWriter f;
                try {

                    f = new FileWriter(mContext.getFilesDir() + fileName
                            + ".txt");
                    f.write(fbFriendList);
                    f.flush();
                    f.close();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

Comment: you need seperator (mContext.getFilesDir()+"/" + fileName+ ".txt");

Answer (score 1):

Better use Path.Combine to create FullPath-Strings:

```
File file = new File(Path.Combine(mContext.getFilesDir(), fileName+ ".txt"));
```

Comment: This is a much better approach but you can just use the `File(String dirPath, String name)` overloaded constructor in this case

Comment: The method Combine(File, String) is undefined for the type Path

Answer (score 1):

You should use the overloaded constructor for file instead of using `+` to concatenate the file path this will add the path separator `/` for you.  Also you can pass the `File` as an argument to the Filewriter constructor instead of repeating yourself with strings:

```
File file = new File(mContext.getFilesDir(), fileName+ ".txt");

FileWriter f;

try {
    f = new FileWriter(file);
    f.write(fbFriendList);
    f.flush();
    f.close();
} catch (IOException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

For more information please refer to the official API documentation for [File](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html) and [FileWriter](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter%28java.io.File%29)

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `"/"`.

```
File file = new File(mContext.getFilesDir() + "/" + fileName+ ".txt");
```

I'd suggest to use [openFileOutput(String name, int mode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)) method - To create and write a private file to the internal storage.

```
Writer out
   = new BufferedWriter(
           new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)));
```

Comment: while this is true it is a bad habit to use operator concatenation.  Better to use the overloaded file constructor

Answer (score 0):

Do this way

```
File file = new File(podcastFolder + File.separator + fileName + ".txt");
```